# Generating pre-signed S3 URL for file with spaces

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I trying to generate a pre-signed URL link for passing to a client. My logic works great as long as the file does not contain spaces. However, if it does I get a "The specified key does not exist." error.

To be clear, I am taking the URL itself and parsing it. So, the key will look something like this when I get it:

```
mybucket/my+file+with+spaces.pdf
```

So, the S3 SDK appears to take the pluses and URL-encodes them to %2b so when the link is clicked it doesn't recognize the path. If I re-write the link putting the '+' back I get the following error:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the answer to my own question. If you just replace the + with " " you will get the proper result.

```
objectKey = file.replace("+", " ");
```

Comment: S3 does some oddball URL encoding that presumably can't be fixed because it has been that way for 10 years.  Where are you getting that original URL with the `+` symbols in it?  I ask, because your solution may be working but incomplete.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for the comment! I am getting a url in an event from another application. that application uploads the docs to a kms encrypted location and passes the event to me. I extract the doc link and generate the expiring link. Do you see any issues with that?

Comment: You should probably use a library that does decoding of the url-escaping and pass the values you get through there. If the filename actually contained a literal `+`, the other app should send you `%2B`, and if you pass that to the SDK it will send it to S3 as `%252B` (escaping the `%` as `%25`) which is also broken, and the same goes for any other percent-encoded literals received.   Using url-decoding on the values you receive should transform these back to normal, so that the SDK has normalized values to work with.  That's why I suspect your fix only fixes the one problem you've seen so far.

Comment: That is great advice @Michael-sqlbot! Thanks! Should have given more time so you could answer!

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot It looks like I always get the link with the '+' in the filename so replacing them with a space seems reasonable. But, if that ever changes it could be delicate. Working on a solution...

Answer (score 0):

Do you get your S3 object key from another event (E.g. SQS, SNS)? So your key might be already URL encoded. Do an URL decode before giving the object key to the pre-sign URL generator.

**Object key should NOT be URL encoded when you are requesting for a presign URL.**

(I'm just writing my experience here so some other person who felt in to the same problem will be beneficial.)